# Parsing multiple Matrices from multiple Files at once

Tags: r, parsing, csv, matrix

I have a folder `Bad` with "bad" samples in form of several csv-Files with numerical values. The idea is to parse to them and use the matrices with the correct column names. The matrices should then be in the list `bad_list`.

```
  setwd("Bad")
  bad <- list.files(pattern="*.csv")
  bad_list = lapply(bad, read.csv, sep = ";", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=TRUE)
```

The result of

```
bad_list[1]
```

is a nice matrix. However, the result for the following

```
colnames(bad_list[1])
ncol(bad_list[1])
```

is `NULL` for both commands. Any ideas?

Comment: A case of `[` vs `[[`? Check `str(bad_list[1])` and `str(bad_list[[1]])`.

Comment: I agree.  Try using `bad_list[[1]]`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/in-r-what-is-the-difference-between-the-and-notations-for-accessing-the/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bad_list[[1]]` does it. `[[ ]]` is the index-operator for lists.